# Parallel examples of the change of Apothēca to boutique?

Tags: language-evolution, phonology, vulgar-latin, irregular-words, romance-languages

French *boutique*, Spanish *bodega* etc. are by etymology said to be from Latin *apothēca* ([REW](https://www.rew-online.gwi.uni-muenchen.de/?id_entry=36099)).

**Are there other cases of word-initial a- being lost in Romance languages?**

From the top of my head, words like French *apparenter* and *allemand* for example haven't change that much. I have also checked *abeille* and *ouvrir*, but the material isn't necessarily complete; s.v. Latin *n. f.* [*ap-](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Latin_feminine_nouns&from=ap):

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nyrop, *Grammaire historique de la langue française* (1914, p. 256) gives the following additional examples (among others) for French:

- *Apulia > Pouille, Aquitania > Guyenne*
- *hemicrania > migraine, hemina > mine, Egertius > le Gers, Aegidius > Gilles*
- *oryza > riz* (borrowed through Italian *riso*)
- *unicornem > licorne*

-- as well as the forms of the definite article, *illum > le* etc.

Answer (score 3):

Loss of an initial vowel is the kind of thing that tends to happen relatively freely. In this case, the fact that it was a greek word, rather than latin, allows it to have been acquired imperfectly, and not in a uniform way across the Empire. For instance, the portuguese version is `adega`, suggesting syncope of the `o` and loss of the `p` rather than apheresis of the `a`.
With actual latin words, the chances of irregular sound change are much lower.